# how to make a query to count, sum, and group by name?

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I want to make a report like this, but I'm having trouble making the query.

| no | merk | tahun | departemen | lokasi | history 2020 | history 2021 | Total (2020+2021) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | machine A | 2014 | Production | LA 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | machine B | 2019 | Production | LA 2 | 0 | 2 | 2 |

and here's my codes for make table.

```
<table id="myTable" width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>NO</th>
                          <th>MERK</th>
                          <th>TAHUN</th>
                          <th>DEPARTEMEN</th>
                          <th>LOKASI</th>
                          <th>HISTORY 2020 (X)</th>
                          <th>HISTORY 2021 (X)</th>
                          <th>TOTAL</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <?php
                      $sql    = "SELECT merk_tmf,tahun_tmf,dept_tmf,lokasi_tmf FROM tb_tmf GROUP BY merk_tmf";
                      $data20 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT merk_tmf FROM tb_tmf WHERE YEAR(waktu_tmf) = 2020 GROUP BY merk_tmf");
                      $data21 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT merk_tmf FROM tb_tmf WHERE YEAR(waktu_tmf) = 2021 GROUP BY merk_tmf");
                      $jumlah = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT merk_tmf FROM tb_tmf GROUP BY merk_tmf");
                      
                      $jumlah20 = mysqli_num_rows($data20);
                      $jumlah21 = mysqli_num_rows($data21);
                      $penjumlahan = mysqli_num_rows($jumlah);

                      $no= 1;
                      $query = $connect->query($sql);
                      while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo 
                            "<tr>
                                <td>". $no++ ."</td>
                                <td>".$row['merk_tmf']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['tahun_tmf']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['dept_tmf']."</td>
                                <td>".$row['lokasi_tmf']."</td>
                                <td>".$jumlah20."</td>
                                <td>".$jumlah21."</td>
                                <td>".$penjumlahan."</td>
                            </tr>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

that data is from this table.

| waktu_tmf | merk_tmf | tahun_tmf | dept_tmf | lokasi_tmf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-06-29 | machine A | 1987 | Production | LA 1 |
| 2021-06-29 | machine A | 1987 | Production | LA 1 |
| 2021-06-29 | machine B | 1990 | Production | LA 2 |
| 2021-06-29 | machine B | 1990 | Production | LA 2 |

I know that there is an error in the query, because I can't make it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run this, I hope this can give you idea...

```
    select merk_tmf merk, tahun_tmf tahun, dept_tmf departemen, lokasi_tmf lokasi,
          sum(case when date_format(waktu_tmf, '%Y') = 2020 then 1 else 0 end) 'history 2020', 
          sum(case when date_format(waktu_tmf, '%Y') = 2021 then 1 else 0 end) 'history 2021', 
          sum((case when date_format(waktu_tmf, '%Y') = 2020 then 1 else 0 end) +
          (case when date_format(waktu_tmf, '%Y') = 2021 then 1 else 0 end)) 'Total (2020+2021)'
    from tb_tmf 
    group by merk_tmf, lokasi_tmf
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.